# Arithmetic Puzzle

Tags: puzzle-identification, calculation-puzzle

The British Independent and *i* newspapers run what they call an "Arithmetic Puzzle", which comprises a grid of nine cells, with each cell separated from the others by arithmetic symbols: (+ - / *), and a "result" row/column to the right and below.  One or two cells have a single digit pre-inserted, and the task is to insert the other digits so that the equations are valid.  Something like this (operations are performed left-to-right and top-to-bottom, not in standard mathematical order):

```
|  1  | x |  3  | x |  4  | =  12 |
|  +  |   |  +  |   |  -  |
|  8  | x |  5  | x |  6  | = 240 |
|  +  |   |  +  |   |  X  |
|  2  | + |  9  | + |  7  | =  18 |
|  =  |   |  =  |   |  =  |
| 11  |   | 17  |   |-14  |
```

Is there a specific name for this sort of puzzle?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling!

Comment: I think they are called *"Cross-Math Puzzles"* (not *"Math-Cross*"!), but right now I can't find any evidence that this is the official name, since you can find the same type of puzzles just by searching *"arithmetic grid"*.

Comment: Closely related but not an exact match: [Number Blocks](http://www.thinkablepuzzles.com/numberblocks/)

Comment: 1 + 3 + 4 = 12 should be 1 x 3 x 4 = 12 (or 1 + 3 + 4 = 8), surely?

Comment: @paolo, Well spotted.  It should have been 1x3x4.  Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simon Tatham's puzzle collection has a manual which refers to them as "small one-player puzzle games". That's a pretty authoritative source, I would expect.

If you're talking about ones that specifically use arithmetic (so including Killer and excluding Sudoku), I doubt there's a better name. You'd probably just replace "puzzle" with "arithmetic", or add "arithmetic" in there somewhere.

Comment: I'm pretty sure rojomoke's question is about a more narrowly defined category of puzzles, and in particular one that includes neither sudoku nor killer sudoku.

Comment: Ah, you could be right. It depend how you read "this sort of puzzle"! But on re-reading your view is probably right